# props.map is not a functions react.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

been working on react js project. But while passing props to child component getting error `props.map` is not a function.

**ParentComponent:-**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('api/dashboard/dashboarddata').then(response => response.json()).then((data: Dashboard) => {
      this.setState({
        category: data.categories,
        banners: data.banners,
        loading: false
      });
    });
  }
```

Passing Props

```
 {
      this.state.loading ? <ContentLoader /> : <div><Category {...this.state.category} /> <Banner {...this.state.banners} /> </div>
 }
```

**This is what state object after API response:-**

[image]

But in child component getting error

[image]

**Child Component:**

```
const Category = (props: brandcategory[]) => {
   
return (
    <div className="section category">
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="section-title">
                        <h4 className="title">Select interested categories</h4>
                        <div className="section-nav">
                            <a className="primary-btn cta-btn" href="#">View All</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <div className="products-tabs">
                                <Slider {...sliderconfig.productSlider} className="products-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-2">
                                    {
                                        props.map((c: brandcategory) => <CategoryCard key={c.id} {...c} />)
                                    }
                                </Slider>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
                            <div className="btn-container">
                                <a href="#" className="btn btn-3">Get Started</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

**Receiving props in child component like this:-**

[image]

Comment: The `props` is an object, you likely meant to map over a ***specific*** prop you passed, like `props.banners.map` or `props.category.map`. Please include all relevant code, what is the component you are trying to map `props` and is throwing the error?

Comment: hi @DrewReese updated my question added child component code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

The `props` is an object, you likely meant to map over a ***specific*** prop you passed, like `props.category.map`. You are actually attempting to spread the entire `this.state.category` array into props.

## Solution

Pass `this.state.category` array as a prop.

```
<Category category={this.state.category} />
```

Then in `Category` component access `props.category` for mapping.

```
props.category.map((c: brandcategory) => <CategoryCard key={c.id} {...c} />)
```

I'm not as familiar with Typescript as I could/should be, but I'm sure you will need to update the component signature. Perhaps something like the following:

```
const Category = ({ category: brandcategory[] }) => { ....
```

And in this case `category` is already destructured from the `props` object, so you won't need to access as `props.category.map` but rather just `category.map`.

```
category.map((c: brandcategory) => <CategoryCard key={c.id} {...c} />)
```

Comment: But can't we pass arry directly in props means is it possible to access `props.map` anyhow?

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh A React component `props` is ***always*** an object, the properties of which ***are*** the props that are passed and accessible by the component.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Drew got it.

Answer (score 2):

You have provided array with spread operators to react component, which must be object as key, value pair must exist. Refer below examples:-

```js
const Category = ({categories}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
    {categories.map((category, index) => (
      <li key={index}>{category.name}</li>
    ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const categories = [{name: 'Apple'}, {name: 'Ball'}];
  return <Category categories={categories} />;
}

const App2 = () => {
  const catProps = {categories: [{name: 'Apple 2'}, {name: 'Ball 2'}]};
  return <Category {...catProps} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App2/>,
  document.getElementById('root2')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h1>Example 1</h1>
<div id="root"></div>

<h1>Example 2</h1>
<div id="root2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because your data is not an array. So .map() function only works with arrays. First, you will need to confirm your data type. and also you will need to transform your data into an array.

Comment: thanks for your answer, adding a code sample would be more helpful